# Regular expression for email or mobile number in one field like facebook email/mobile field in registration

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs, validation, preg-match

**Regular expression for email or mobile number in one field like facebook email/mobile field in registration**
I am building a registration form in in which i am trying a make a field say email/mobile where user can either put email address or mobile number with country code.similiar approach is used in facebook registration.can anyone have solution for such regular expression. i am building the form using angularjs with its default validator.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com, please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: SO is not a site to request solutions. Try *something* and show what you did. We will help you figure out how to fix if it doesn't work.

Comment: i have email validation regular expression and mobile validation regular expression.so i want to know how they can be combine together and put it in single field.

Answer (score 0):

I use this for email in python. The syntax should be the same in js
"^[\S]+@[\S]+.[\S]+$"

as far as phone number goes, there's a lot of ways it could go.
You may just want them to type 10 numbers:
[0-9]{10}

but what if they are in a place that still uses 7 numbers? or they are international (international codes are 2-3 digits)?
[0-9]{10}|[0-9]{7}|[0-9]{12,13}

but what if they decide to put hyphens in?
[0-9]{10}|[0-9]{7}|[0-9]{13}|([0-9]{2,3})?-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}

now I think we can smush this together to make something more interesting, making the hyphens optional.
^(([0-9]{2,3})-?)?([0-9]{3}-?)?[0-9]{3}-?[0-9]{4}

Lastly make sure to break your tests in a decision tree like if...else so you can get different logic for whatever the user decides to put in.

corollary:
this does match 123-4567890
as well as 123456-7890
But you might want to accept that input in good faith.

Comment: Ok, how to make two regular expression mutually exclusive in one field,like in facebook email or mobile validation,user can put either mobile or email.

Comment: like I said in the post if (emailre.match(userinput)){ do email stuff} else if(phonere.match(userinput)){do phone stuff}

Comment: Cant we create a common regular expression for it which we can match either email or mobile.if it is not possible then i think you solution for the problem will be effective

Comment: a common expression doesn't give you the flexibility to do something different depending on its form